# How to group similar column values in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I want to group column values using scala, for example

```
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes
```

I want the result as,

**For Ist column.........**

Ist group

```
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no
```

IInd group

```
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes
```

IIIrd group

```
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
```

**For IInd column.........**

Ist group

```
hot,high,FALSE,no
hot,high,TRUE,no
hot,high,FALSE,yes
```

IInd group

```
cool,normal,FALSE,yes
cool,normal,TRUE,yes
```

IIIrd group

```
mild,high,FALSE,yes
```

Similarly all columns upto second last column ............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Seq.groupBy` method.

```
val data = Seq(("sunny", "hot", "high", "FALSE", "no"),
  ("sunny", "hot", "high", "TRUE", "no"),
  ("overcast", "hot", "high", "FALSE", "yes"),
  ("rainy", "mild", "high", "FALSE", "yes"),
  ("rainy", "cool", "normal", "FALSE", "yes"),
  ("overcast", "cool", "normal", "TRUE", "yes"))

val byFirst = data.groupBy(_._1)
```

Result:

```
Map(
    overcast -> List((overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes), (overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes)), 
    rainy -> List((rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes), (rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes)), 
    sunny -> List((sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no), (sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no)))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to group by all columns upto second last column.

Comment: Then call groupBy again with _._2, _._3 or whatever